# Can I manually eager load a model with data in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

For example say I have Book and Author models. I'd eager load the authors like this:

```
$books = Book::with('author')->get();
```

But I have already fetched the list of authors with `Author::all()` in order to display them elsewhere on the page (a select field for filtering). So now Laravel executes 3 queries:

```
select * from authors;
select * from books;
select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, ...);
```

The third query is obviously superfluous since I already have the authors. Is there some way to pass my `$authors` Collection into my Book query? Searched through the docs and API and can't find anything.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not familiar with any way of circumventing the query builder approach to eager loading. You could perhaps do it the other way around: `$authors = Author::with('books')->get();` to get the authors, then `$books = $authors->pluck('books')->unique();` (or similar). Would reduce the queries by one, but using `Collection` logic can still be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this custom code

```
$authors = Author::get();
$books = Book::get();

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $author = $authors->where('id', $book->author_id)->first();
    $book->setRelation('author', $author);
}
```